# Preciso adicionar uma Curva de suavisação em modelo GAM

Tags: r

Fiz um GAM mas preciso colocar no meu gráfico uma curva de suavisação um smoot.line para melhor visualização da curva de decaimento de sinal.

```
rt:

Date    Time    ID  Sinal (dB)  Gain (dB)   Dist
23/04/2019  16:24:19    22948   54  48  450
23/04/2019  16:24:05    22948   55  48  450
23/04/2019  16:23:51    22948   54  48  450
23/04/2019  16:06:07    22948   56  48  350
23/04/2019  16:05:27    22948   55  48  350
23/04/2019  16:04:59    22948   54  48  350
23/04/2019  15:32:28    22948   64  6   250
23/04/2019  15:20:39    22948   71  6   200
23/04/2019  15:19:58    22948   65  6   200
23/04/2019  15:23:09    22948   55  48  200
23/04/2019  15:22:55    22948   58  48  200
23/04/2019  14:57:00    22948   64  48  100
23/04/2019  14:56:46    22948   64  48  100
23/04/2019  14:56:32    22948   80  6   100
23/04/2019  14:26:59    22948   65  48  0
23/04/2019  14:26:45    22948   106 6   0
23/04/2019  14:26:31    22948   105 6   0
```

Segue meu código

```
library(gam)
gam(Sinal..dB.~Dist, data=rt)->mod
mod
summary(mod)
plot(mod,se=TRUE)
```

Obrigada.

Answer (score 3):

Em R há várias funções para suavizar um conjunto de dados, seguem-se `loess` e `smooth.spline`.

```
lfit <- loess(`Sinal (dB)` ~ Dist, data = rt)
sfit <- smooth.spline(rt$Dist, rt$`Sinal (dB)`)
ypred_loess <- predict(lfit)

plot(`Sinal (dB)` ~ Dist, data = rt)
lines(ypred_loess ~ Dist, data = rt)
lines(sfit$x, sfit$y, col = "blue", lty = "dotted")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### Dados

Os dados são lidos com `read.table` mas com o argumento `check.names = FALSE`, o que parece faltar na pergunta. O nome de coluna `'Sinal (dB)'` não tem os espaços e os parêntesis substituídos por espaços.

```
dados_txt <- "
Date    Time    ID  'Sinal (dB)'  'Gain (dB)'   Dist
23/04/2019  16:24:19    22948   54  48  450
23/04/2019  16:24:05    22948   55  48  450
23/04/2019  16:23:51    22948   54  48  450
23/04/2019  16:06:07    22948   56  48  350
23/04/2019  16:05:27    22948   55  48  350
23/04/2019  16:04:59    22948   54  48  350
23/04/2019  15:32:28    22948   64  6   250
23/04/2019  15:20:39    22948   71  6   200
23/04/2019  15:19:58    22948   65  6   200
23/04/2019  15:23:09    22948   55  48  200
23/04/2019  15:22:55    22948   58  48  200
23/04/2019  14:57:00    22948   64  48  100
23/04/2019  14:56:46    22948   64  48  100
23/04/2019  14:56:32    22948   80  6   100
23/04/2019  14:26:59    22948   65  48  0
23/04/2019  14:26:45    22948   106 6   0
23/04/2019  14:26:31    22948   105 6   0
"
tc <- textConnection(dados_txt)
rt <- read.table(tc, header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
close(tc)
```

Comment: Obrigada! É possível fazer o gráfico sem as bolinhas dos valores, mostrar apenas as linhas? Ou então fazer pelo ggplot com a curva de suavização em azul e cinza escuro? Obrigada.

Comment: @FrancielleOliveira Para omitir os pontos, basta incluir o argumento `type` na instrução ``plot(`Sinal (dB)` ~ Dist, data = rt, type = "n")``

Comment: Rui, ao adicionar o argumento type = "n" desaparece os pontos e as linhas também. O gráfico fica em branco.

Comment: @FrancielleOliveira Sim, o gráfico fica em branco até traçar as linhas das duas instruções seguintes. É necessário iniciar o dispositivo gráfico (*graphics device*) com o `plot` em branco, que traça os eixos com tamanho suficiente para os dados e anotações, nomes, etc. Não é isso que quer?

Comment: Isso, deu certo. Obrigada!